# stuck at Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 31.2.10)"

Tags: android-emulator

while installing the android emulator mine was stuck at
[image]

os Linux: manjaro

```
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 31.2.10)". 
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux_x64-8420304.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cancel the download process and run it again it worked for me but don't know whats the problem tho

Answer (score 1):

It will take some time to install. Hence do not cancel the process. In my case, it took 20 to 30 minutes.

If you already canceled the installing process then you can delete the android sdk from the location it resides in your machine and re-run the installation.

Also for Apple silicon chip, it worked with the custom setup.

Answer (score 0):

+1
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 31.3.10)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip
Warning: This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8807927.zip

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only need to wait a little ... Maybe the download take some time, but after 10 minutes the installer works just fine ... (just wait a few minutes... )